# Line numbering paragraph oriented?

Tags: line-numbering

I'm using the `lineno` package with the `pagewise` option but I need a way to get the numbering restart every paragraph break. I need a general solution to pass to the `latex` command, e.g.:

```
latex "\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage[pagewise]{lineno}\linenumbers}\input{mydocument.tex}"
```

I read the `lineno` manual but the package does not provide this feature. Is there any trick to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use running linenumbers which are reset to 1 for each paragraph. The reset can be automated using a hook to the `\par` command (which also works for paragraphs created by empty lines).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[excludeor]{everyhook}
\usepackage[running]{lineno}
\runninglinenumbers
\PushPreHook{par}{\resetlinenumber[1]}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

The same result can be obtained with `\AtBeginDocument`, as follows:

```
pdflatex "\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage[excludeor]{everyhook}\RequirePackage[running]{lineno}\runninglinenumbers\PushPreHook{par}{\resetlinenumber[1]}}\input{mydocument.tex}"
```

of course provided that `mydocument.tex` is something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! You win! It's exactly what I need. Thank you.